# how to upgrade a module in azure iot edge

Tags: azure-iot-edge

I am trying to understand how continuous delivery of modules would work.
I have an image that I versioned 0.0.1, I then modify and add new functionality and want to call it 0.0.2 as it is not applicable to all my fleet.

This is what I do:
-   I go in the module.json and step the version . 
-   I choose ‘build and push’ in the VC context menu
-   I verify that the new version is correctly tagged in the repo 
-   I choose ‘create deployment for single device’ in the VC context menu 
-   I get:
[Edge] Start deployment to device [edgeVM]
[Edge] Deployment succeeded.
-   Still, nothing happens in edgeAgent and the module never gets updated

What steps am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Increasing the version number in **module.json** is correct but not sufficient.  You also have to increase the version number of that module in the **deployment.template.json** because that's where it's defined which version of the module is to be used by the device.